# Generic Repository with stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have implemented Generic repository and UOW using this link
  http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/

Now I want to call stored procedure.I am using Entity Framework version 5.
Please advice me How to call a stored procedure